# How to subset in dplyr with the same conditions among multiple variables

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, subset

I have a list of variables in sequence and I was wondering if there was a simple way of subsetting in dplyr with same conditions among the sequence of variables.

For example, I have the following variables:

DX1
DX2
DX3
DX4
DX5

I would like a subset of my data if any of those variables contains the following string '7586'.

Subsetting from a single variable I would do the following:

```
filter(df, DX1 == '7586')
```

The only method I can think of would be the following:

```
filter(df, DX1 == '7586' | DX2 == '7586' | DX3 == '7586' | DX4 == '7586' | DX5 == '7586')
```

My actual dataset contains DX1-DX25 and it can get quite tedious to write.

Is there a method of simplifying the above?

something along the lines of

```
filter(df, DX1-25 == '7586')
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options, one in base R, and one in `dplyr`, should produce the same result:

```
df[rowSums(df == 7586) > 0,]
```

or

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   filter(rowSums(. == 7586) > 0)
```

and a `data.table` version for fun, which should eek out a tiny bit more speed if necessary:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, `==`, 7586) ) > 0] ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all the options!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like, if DX1 ~ DX25 are all or most of the columns of your data.frame?

```
df[apply(df, 1, function(row) any(row == '7586')), ]

     x    y
1 7586  322
2 3322 7586
```

**Data**:

```
structure(list(x = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("3322", "7586"
), class = "factor"), y = structure(1:2, .Label = c("322", "7586"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select(data, DX1:DX25) %>% apply(., 1, function(x) any(x == '7586')) %>% data[. , ]
```